why is my loop not working in below solidity code
What's happening here in the code and why is my loop not working? And one more thing, should I remove all the warnings from my code before deploying?
function sub(uint n, uint a) external pure returns(uint) {
    for(uint i=1; i<100; i++) {
        uint b;
        b += n+a;
        return b;
    }
}



What exactly you want to achieve with your sub function?

Please, use text to show source code. It will be much easier to test.


You are using 'return' inside a loop, so the code will return and stop the loop on the first iteration.

You can keep the warnings; they won't stop your code from working. However, it's better to always fix all warnings.



ohhh got it thankyou.
